# SQL Server Add Default datetime column for existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, crud

I want to have a new column in the table that will show the date and time of the inserts, but without modifying the queries to include the column itself.

I have added the new column in the following way:

```
ALTER TABLE DBO.HOURLYMODULETIMES
ADD CreateTime datetime DEFAULT NOT NULL getdate()
```

This adds the values to previous entries, but when I try to INSERT INTO the table without including the new column

```
INSERT INTO DBO.HOURLYMODULETIMES VAlUES
(99999999,11111,2222,'JA')
```

Table has 5 columns ID, AVGMODULETIME, SUMHOURS, USERNAME, CreateTime(newly added). I get the following error:

```
 Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Is it possible to create such a column without modifying the queries?

Comment: Show us the INSERT as well!

Comment: @jarlh INSERT INTO DBO.HOURLYMODULETIMES VALUES
  (99999999,11111,2222,'TEST'). The table has columns ID, AVGMODULETIME, SUMHOURS, USERNAME, CreateTime

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the columns now when you want to omit one of them when doing `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO DBO.HOURLYMODULETIMES (ID, AVGMODULETIME, SUMHOURS, USERNAME)
VALUES (99999999,11111,2222,'TEST')
```

It's good programming practice to always do this, since table definitions may change over time - as you have noticed!

Comment: That means that the insert queries need to be modified. Because I'm modifying a system where I have no access to the "frontend" queries that were added. Hoping for a solution that can somehow circle around that.

Comment: That's a major problem. Can be solved with views to retain backward compatibility.

Comment: Aren't views just copying from original tables? Even if I add some say calculated or default column there, it still wouldn't show the exact time of insert of the original row, which is what I need.

Comment: Create a new table including the CreateTime column. Move data. Create a view DBO.HOURLYMODULETIMES with only the old columns, replacing that table.